# One command for ls and cat functionality?

Tags: command-line, scripts, alias, ls, cat

Okay guys, this is an experimental question warning!

I often confuse `cat` and `ls` when quickly working on the console. Not because I forget their meanings, no. Just because I type without deeply thinking about the command - it just comes automatically. I am sure everyone knows what I am trying to explain: you don't have to think what to type if your task is to list, say, a text file - or a directory.

Now, why two different commands?
Things would be more fluently if there was a command that lists a directory if the target is a directory and that lists the content of a file if the target is a file.

Does such a command exist?

I know there are editors (e. g. `vim`) with the ability to list a directory. But this is not what I want, as I want to stay on the console. Second, after opening a file through the `vim` directory listing there is no way back - at least none that I know.

If there is no out-of-the-box solution I will try to make a small bash script (wrapper) to `cat` and `ls`. But this is not preferred, because when working with many different systems it has to be placed on each of them...

Comment: Emacs is having a mode for shell and for directory browsing ... (SCNR)

Comment: Did you read my paragraph about the vim directory browsing mode? If yes, is emacs different/better here? In the end I don't want to leave the console into an application for actions beyond the cat/ls scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply put this function is your `.bashrc`:

```
catls()
{
  [[ -f "$1" ]] && cat "$1" || ls "$1";
}
```

It will `cat` regular files but call `ls` for directories

Comment: if this is for bash, then use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `test <TEST> `or `[ ... ]`.  `[ ... ]` and `test <TEST>` are [deprecated syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) and should only be used when `[[ ... ]]` is _not_ available.

Comment: @AlexejMagura, thanks for the deprecation notice, I've updated my answer

Comment: Also note, that if `$1` is a file or path containing a space: this function will break because `$1` is not double quoted.

Comment: @AlexejMagura: Good point

Comment: This is soooo awesome that I exagerated Sylvain's function body to `[[ $# -gt 1 ]] && cp "$1" "$2" || ([[ -f "$1" ]] && cat "$1" || ([[ $# -ge 1 ]] && ls -l "$1" || ls -l));` - this is awesome, crazy and magic at once! :D

Comment: Nice Swiss knife :)

Comment: On a side note, `$1` won't break on expansion if unquoted inside `[[]]`, `[[]]` is smarter than `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Hate to necrobump and unable to just comment; but fix for when nothing is passed.

```
catls() { [[ -f "$1" ]] && cat "$1" || ls "${1:-.}"; }
```